# reading .csv file into a struct that's included from header

Tags: c, csv, struct, header

I'm trying to read a csv. file into a struct, and the struct was created in a separate .h file and included as #include "filedata.h". I'm having trouble reading into the struct however.

My struct is defined in my filedata.h file as

```
#ifndef filedata
#define filedata

typedef struct {
     char *data1;
     char *data2;
     char yN;
}filedata;

#endif
```

And my .c file contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "filedata.h"

filedata data[5]; //instantiates struct?

int main(){

const char s[3] = ", ";
int i = 0;
char line [256];
char *temp;

FILE *fp = fopen("filename.csv", "r");
if(fp==NULL){
   perror("File not found!\n");
   return 1;}

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
   temp = strtok(line, s);
   strcpy(data[i].&data1, temp);
   <etc>
   i++;}
fclose(fp);
}
```

I keep getting an "expected identifier before '&' token". How can I properly access the struct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reserve space for the string `data[i].data1`, use `malloc` before `strcpy`:

```
size_t sz = strlen(temp) + 1;

/* You don't need the address of (&) operator, data1 is already a pointer */
data[i].data1 = malloc(sz);
if (data[i].data1 == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(data[i].data1, temp);
```

Or `strdup` (not standard but available on many implementations):

```
data[i].data1 = strdup(temp);
if (data[i].data1 == NULL) {
    perror("strdup");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Don't forget to `free(data[i].data1);` when no longer needed in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your advice helped eliminate many problems but now I receive the error "request for member "data1" in something not a structure or union". Any advice?

Comment: It seems that you are using `.` instead of `->` or viceversa somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy(data[i].&data1, temp);` that is a syntax error because you cannot take a reference in the middle of a variable.

You don't need a reference at all since `data1` field is already a pointer on char. You just need to properly allocate (duplicate) the string and assign like this:

```
data[i].data1 = strdup(strtok(line, s))
```

That's because `strtok` doesn't allocate memory for you, returned values are bound to `line` (next line read: your data would be lost)

(BTW no need for `temp`)